# Programmatically check to see if calendar has been rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

This should be simple, but I'm stupid so...

I want to do a simple conditional statement to see if the calendar has already been rendered within a div.  Something like this:

```
if ( $('#calendar').fullCalendar() )
{
  alert("calendar exists!!");
}
```

I want to do this so that I can remove, then re-init the calendar programatically. Basically, a 'reset' button.

Can someone please let me know the proper syntax to check if a fullCalendar object has been rendered?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. jQuery has a `.children()` selector. I was able to do a conditional statement on the `.length` property of that selector to see if there was any content in the div:

```
if ( $('#calendar').children().length > 0 ) {
    alert("calendar exists!!");
}
```

An alternative way to do this, without jQuery, is:

```
getElementById('calendar').hasChildNodes()
```

Comment: If you select for something deeper in the calendar's structure you'll be more likely to catch it after it's done rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack, but each day cell has a class with the format `fc-day-##`. The last cell has the number 41 (check it out in firebug). You could try to select `td.fc-da-41` and if you get any elements then the calendar is fully loaded.

```
if ($('td.fc-day-41').size() > 0) {
    //calendar ready
}
```

Maybe set it to check every couple hundred milliseconds with `.setTimeout()`

```
var checkCal = function() {
    if ($('td.fc-day-41').size() > 0) {
        //calendar ready
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(checkCal(), 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check something like easily

```
if($('#calendar>*').length !== 0) alert("calendar exists!!");
```